# Where can I find an example of Decentralized Identifiers

Tags: decentralized-identity, decentralized-identifiers

1. I am looking for examples that use Decentralized Identifiers to run on my computer, but it seems that is hard to find one. I have also searched for an example that works with Microsoft ION, but I couldn't find anyone. I also don't know if Microsoft ION is working correctly (yes, I have followed the installation guide). Does anyone know any example that is running about Decentralized Identifiers?
2. Why it is becoming so hard to find Decentralized Identifiers examples?

Answer (score 0):

Commenting on question 1 specifically regarding ION:

> I also don't know if Microsoft ION is working correctly

It is more accurate to refer ION as just "ION" as opposed to "Microsoft ION", unless you are referring the ION node that Microsoft runs. To be clear, ION is an open, permission-less network. While Microsoft is a key contributor to ION's development, it does not "own" it in anyway. Assuming you mean you don't know if your own ION node is running correctly or not, a test you can do is to perform a DID resolution against your own node as well against the Microsoft's ION node ([for example](https://beta.discover.did.microsoft.com/1.0/identifiers/did:ion:EiClkZMDxPKqC9c-umQfTkR8vvZ9JPhl_xLDI9Nfk38w5w)), you should be getting the same response/DID Document.

> Why it is becoming so hard to find Decentralized Identifiers examples?

While do think there is a point to be made about not having a lot of examples using DIDs out there, I do think that we are still at the initial phase of DID adoption and it is becoming easier, not harder to find actual usage.

As an example, Microsoft's [Verifiable Credentials offering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/decentralized-identifier-overview) relies on ION DIDs for credential issuers as well as credential holders/subjects.